# Finding elements not in a string present in another string in python

Tags: python, string

Python.

```
   Str1="acddeffg" 
   Str2="fgfdeca"
```

I want to obtain the letter/s that are in `Str1` not present in `Str2` and viceversa.

In this example is `Np1="", Np2="d"`

```
    Str1="abcdefffg"
    Str2="aabcdef"
```

Answer `Np1="a", Np2="ffg"`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Re-reading your question, you probably want to do this:

```py
str1 = "abcdefffg"
str2 = "aabcdef"

def find_diff(left, right):

    l = list(left)
    for letter in right:
        if letter in l:
            l.remove(letter)
    
    return "".join(l)
    
print(find_diff(str1, str2))  # ffg
print(find_diff(str2, str1))  # a
```

---

Original answer: You could use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)s to get the difference between used letters (ignoring duplicates). Not what the OP is looking for (second example) but I will leave it here for reference.

```py
letters1 = set("abcdefffg")
letters2 = set("aabcdef")

print(letters1 - letters2)  # {'g'}
print(letters2 - letters1)  # set()
```

Comment: Sets won’t work. The example output OP provided shows duplicate characters.

Comment: Just realized it myself and updated it a few seconds ago :)

Comment: That's no works, because I need to obtain "ffg" AND "a". 
The repetitions must be taken into account

Comment: Did you see my update? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Np1 = ''.join([letter for letter in Str1 if letter not in Str2])

Np2 = ''.join([letter for letter in Str2 if letter not in Str1])
```

Comment: That's no works, because I need to obtain "ffg" and "a. repetitions must be taken into account.
With yor method I obtain "g"  and  ""